# Anyone using Moonlight?

Tags: moonlight

Has anyone used Moonlight for real time app development? Is it really worth spending time with it?

-Fahad

Answer (score 1):

Moonlight is silverlight for linux and other platforms where Microsoft doesn't provide an implementation.
You don't need to do anything to develop for moonlight, just develop your application and target for Silverlight 2.0 or 3.0.
This way it will run on Moonlight without any problem.

Comment: My original question if it can be used for APP development so you don't use Visual Studio to create Silverlight Apps and make them running in Moonlight. Anyway this question was posted long long back, and I know that its futile now. May be Moonlight has some future when it comes to iOS and Android.

Comment: Actually, I've been having plenty of fun recently writing desktop apps that use moonlight, https://github.com/inorton/MoonBase and https://github.com/inorton/XamlPreviewer. Moonlight 4.x will be awesome and should be out quite soon

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on you! and your time. Its Silverlight anyhow. Or for say like Mono Tools they are always useful. In my opinion it doesn't worth that much! Cheers!